# Why is my timer not initiating in my Web Form project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When I run the program, there is no console output. I have attempted a few other timer procedures and to no avail.

Code Snippet:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());


        System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
        aTimer.Interval = 3000;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;

    }

    private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: As AndrewP's answer below states, you could try puting the 4 lines for timer at the start, before `Application.EnableVisualStyles();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Application.Run(new Form1());` is a blocking call. It basically just sits there until you close your application.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.run(v=vs.110).aspx

To check it out, put a break point on the entry to the `Main()` function, and debug-step through your application!